# Working with modbus C #

Tags: c#, modbus

There is a controller working on the modbus rtu protocol. I need to write an application to poll. There are two implementation options, one through the nmodbus library, the second without the use of libraries. The problem is that different results are returned. Tell me what the problem is.

This is a code version using the nmodbus library.

```
SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort();
        serialPort.PortName = "COM6";
        serialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        serialPort.DataBits = 8;
        serialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        serialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;

        serialPort.Open();

        ModbusSerialMaster master = ModbusSerialMaster.CreateRtu(serialPort);

        byte slaveID = 2;
        ushort startAddress = 0x5E4;
        ushort numOfPoints = 1;

        ushort[] holding_register = master.ReadHoldingRegisters(slaveID, startAddress, numOfPoints); 

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPoints; i++)
        {

            int tmpStart = Convert.ToInt32(startAddress + i);
            String tempStart = Convert.ToString(tmpStart, 16); 

            int tmpReg = Convert.ToInt32(holding_register[i]);
            String tempReg = Convert.ToString(tmpReg, 16);

            Console.WriteLine("Register {0}={1}", startAddress + i, holding_register[i]);
        } 
        serialPort.Close();
```

Outputs that there is a number 7.

Here is the second code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort mySerialPort = new SerialPort("COM6");
        mySerialPort.BaudRate = 19200;
        mySerialPort.Parity = Parity.None;
        mySerialPort.StopBits = StopBits.One;
        mySerialPort.DataBits = 8;
        mySerialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        mySerialPort.ReadTimeout = 450;
        mySerialPort.WriteTimeout = 3000;

        mySerialPort.Open();

        mySerialPort.Write(ReadHoldingRegister(02, 0x5E4, 1), 0, 8);

        byte[] response = ReadExact(mySerialPort.BaseStream, 1);

        for (int i = 0; i < response.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Register = {0}", response[i]);
        }

        mySerialPort.Close();
    }

    public static byte[] ReadExact(Stream s, int nbytes)
    {
        var buf = new byte[nbytes];
        var readpos = 0;
        while (readpos < nbytes)
            readpos += s.Read(buf, readpos, nbytes - readpos);
        return buf;
    }

    public static byte[] ReadHoldingRegister(int id, int startAddress, int length)
    {
        byte[] data = new byte[8];
        byte High, Low;

        data[0] = Convert.ToByte(id);
        data[1] = Convert.ToByte(3);

        byte[] _adr = BitConverter.GetBytes(startAddress - 1);

        data[2] = _adr[1];
        data[3] = _adr[0];

        byte[] _length = BitConverter.GetBytes(length);

        data[4] = _length[1];
        data[5] = _length[0];

        myCRC(data, 6, out High, out Low);

        data[6] = Low;
        data[7] = High;

        return data;
    }

    public static void myCRC(byte[] message, int length, out byte CRCHigh, out byte CRCLow)
    {
        ushort CRCFull = 0xFFFF;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull ^ message[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {
                if ((CRCFull & 0x0001) == 0)
                    CRCFull = (ushort)(CRCFull >> 1);
                else
                {
                    CRCFull = (ushort)((CRCFull >> 1) ^ 0xA001);
                }
            }
        }
        CRCHigh = (byte)((CRCFull >> 8) & 0xFF);
        CRCLow = (byte)(CRCFull & 0xFF);
    }
}
```

Outputs that there is a number 2.

And the old program displays such an answer: 02 03 05 E4 00 01 02 03 02 00 07

Comment: In your first example, nmodbus ReadHoldingRegister processes the response packet and returns an array of holding registers (from the packet).  In your second example, you are only reading (and printing) the first byte in the response packet (which should be a 2; that address of the device that you sent in the request).

Comment: @Marker  Well, but how can I do it so that everything will be fine?

Comment: Have you read the Modbus spec (http://www.modbus.org/docs/Modbus_Application_Protocol_V1_1b3.pdf)?  It will show you what the response "packet" will look like.  You really need to run the response though a CRC check first to make sure the "packet" is valid and then you have to parse it.  In addition to a valid response It is possible that it is either an exception response or event a response to a different request if you are not waiting enough time between requests.